# get_permalink returns default link

Tags: posts, permalinks, url-rewriting

I hope you can help me.

So I'm using `/%postname%/` as permalink structure, and my htaccess looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /develop/sekai/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /develop/sekai/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Hovewer, `get_permalink` function returns me the default permalink structure (`?page_id=x`), while menus are fine with their links.

What should I do? Thanks for all!! :D

Comment: This is answered at http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_permalink-returns-default-link

Comment: Did you get the answer?